# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I´m trying to do an update with PDO and I´m getting an error that Im not detecting where the problem is.

**The error is this**:
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in $updateCategory->execute();

Someone there have any idea why this is happening?

```
$urledit = $_GET['edit'];
$f['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$f['content'] = $_POST['content'];
$f['tags'] = $_POST['tags'];
$f['date'] = $_POST['date'];


$updateCategory = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE categories SET name=:name, url=:url, content=:content, tags=:tags, date=:date WHERE id=:urledit");  
$updateCategory->bindValue(':name', $f['name']);
$updateCategory->bindValue(':url', $f['url']);
$updateCategory->bindValue(':content', $f['content']);
$updateCategory->bindValue(':tags', $f['tags']);
$updateCategory->bindValue(':date', $f['date']);
$updateCategory->bindValue(':id', $urledit);
$updateCategory->execute();
echo 'Update Sucessed!';
```

Comment: how u have both GET and POST on the same page ? `$urledit = $_GET['edit'];` and rest all POST ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and Im using the post for my form fields and then get to get my edit url variable!

Comment: You can send both haha GET uses the URL so say he could of submitted a form with the action="handler.php?edit=true" and then submit the reset with the POST action haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `:urledit` to `:id` in your query. All the bind values must match in the query.

Comment: Thank you. It was really that the problem! It is my first update with PDO so I´m still a bit jumbled. Thanks :)

Comment: You are using a PDO, that is really great to hear, its always sad to see new code being written with the deprecated `mysql_*` :)

Answer (score 4):

Victory's answer is correct but please don't bind every parameter like that, PDO is awesome and the execute functions allows you to pass an array which ill bind them for you :) also if your only using the variable once there's no point to declaring it as a variable an example of this would be,

**PHP**

```
$parameters = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
    ':url' => $_POST['url'], 
    ':content' => $_POST['content'], 
    ':tags' => $_POST['tags'], 
    ':date' => $_POST['date'], 
    ':urledit' => $_GET['edit'])
);

$updateCategory = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE categories 
                                 SET name = :name, url = :url, content = :content, tags = :tags, date = :date 
                                 WHERE id = :urledit");

if($updateCategory->execute($parameters)) {
    echo 'Update Sucessed!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line needs to change:

```
$updateCategory->bindValue(':id', $urledit);
```

to this:

```
$updateCategory->bindValue(':urledit', $urledit);
```

Because in this line:

```
$updateCategory = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE categories SET name=:name, url=:url, content=:content, tags=:tags, date=:date WHERE id=:urledit");
```

you reference the placeholder `:urledit` rather than `:id`.